# PHP preg_replace_callback replace wrong open and end tags

Tags: preg-replace

I'm having a problem with my BB-Code function. I've tested followig input to replace:

```
Testtext! <b>text<u>testtext</u>test</b><b>test</b>
```

and get this (mixed) output:

```
Testtext! [b]text[u]testtext[/u]test</b>test<b>test[/b]
```

my PHP-Code:

```
function html_to_bbcode($input) {
$regex[] = '#\<b>((?:[^[]|\<(?!/?b>)|(?R))+)\</b>#im';
$regex[] = '#\<i>((?:[^[]|\<(?!/?i>)|(?R))+)\</i>#im';
$regex[] = '#\<u>((?:[^[]|\<(?!/?u>)|(?R))+)\</u>#im';

if (is_array($input)) {
    $tag = explode('>', $input[0]);
    $tag = str_replace('<', '', $tag[0]);
if ($tag == 'b') {
    $input = '[b]'.$input[1].'[/b]';
} else if ($tag == 'i') {
    $input = '[i]'.$input[1].'[/i]';
} else if ($tag == 'u') {
    $input = '[u]'.$input[1].'[/u]';
}
}
return preg_replace_callback($regex, 'html_to_bbcode', $input);
}
```

(and some more Tags)

I can't find that bug :( Have anyone an solution for this?

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: This: Testtext! `[b]text[u]testtext[/u]test[/b]test[b]test[/b]`
I think PHP don't know, where the end of the tag is.

Comment: You should specify this in your answer.

Comment: BB-Code should this output be.
I would convert this (html) `Testtext! <b>text<u>testtext</u>test</b><b>test</b>` to BB-Code: `Testtext! [b]text[u]testtext[/u]test[/b][b]test[/b]`